# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

I'm doing the merge sort in python but I have a problem. When I try to insert the list from the console (one number per line which return a list of string) I cannot convert it in integers. Can you help me understanding the problem.

```
import sys

def mergeSort(lista):
    res = []
    for i in lista[0].split():
        res.append(int(i))
    if len(res)>1:
        mid = len(res)//2
        lefthalf = res[:mid]
        righthalf = res[mid:]
        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)
        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i]<righthalf[j]:
                res[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                res[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            res[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            res[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print(res)

alist = []
for l in sys.stdin:
    alist.append(l.strip())
mergeSort(alist)
```

The code error says: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
The input is a file (given from the shell with the command: "python3 merge.py < data.txt") with the list of numbers one per line. 
Example:
    2 
    3
    0
    12
    11
    7
    4
Should return 0 2 3 4 7 11 12
Of course I don't have an output because of the error

Comment: All this means is the first item in `lista` is an `int` object, not a string.  Somehow your code is is appending an integer to the list you're passing in.  So this can't be a complete code example...

Comment: but they are all one unit string...

Comment: The only place your code shows that uses `str.split()` is on an element of a list that ostensibly contains strings.  You're probably not looking at the same code you're running, or you didn't post the same code you're running here.

Comment: I can swear the code is the same. When I try to output the "lista", it returns:

'1\r3\r4\r56\r65\r3\r4\r3\r2\r9\r10'

Comment: I see now on closer inspection.  When you call `mergeSort` recursively you're passing in a list of integers rather than a list of strings.  You should handle the conversion from strings to integers outside the `mergeSort` routine.

Comment: If you put this as answer I will give you the 10 points man!!!!

Comment: When in doubt, [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is your friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting a list of strings to a list of integers at the top of your `mergeSort` routine.  The subsequent recursive calls to `mergeSort` are trying to do the same, except now to lists of integers.

You should handle all file parsing completely separate from your `mergeSort` routine which should be designed just to work on a list of numbers.  This is a "separation of concerns".

Comment: Absolutely right. I did the correction. Should I have to put the corrected code upstair?

Comment: If you wish. It might be better for future readers to see both versions, or least the relevant updates (not necessarily two full versions of the code since the merge sort details don't matter).

Answer (score 2):

If you also want the index, you can use `enumerate`:

```
data = ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC', 'itemD']
for (i, item) in enumerate(data):
    print("Item #%d is %s" % (i, str(item)))
```

For future reference, you can debug like so:

```
def mergeSort(lista):
    res = []
    print(lista)
    for i in lista[0].split():
        print(i)
        res.append(int(i))
```

Comment: Add the print statements to see the contents of the variable `lista` before the loop starts, and the contents of `i` at the beginning of each iteration -- they might not be what you expect.

Comment: And indeed it was not the output I was looking for. The output of the lista is  '1\r3\r4\r56\r65\r3\r4\r3\r2\r9\r10' (That's why I was using split) and I cannot output 'i' because of the error in the loop

Answer (score 1):

It should be `for i in lista` rather than `for i in lista[0].split()`, and you can simply achieve it by list comprehension: `res = [int(num) for num in lista]`

Comment: I already do it and I receive the error:  invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\r3\r4\r56\r65\r3\r4\r3\r2\r9\r10'

Comment: That's why I did split

Comment: @user28011994 Are you sure in your data.txt is one number per line? Looks like your `alist` contains only 1 element with all the numbers in it, which is weird.

Comment: I wrote it as 1 number per line

Answer (score 0):

You're running this code in Python 2 and you only entered a single number. If that's true, replace input with raw_input and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
[image: Can anyone help me with this]