# Attribute error even after adding the enumerate

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I keep getting Attributeerror such as 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'.
At first I did not have enumerate in this code, and I got attribute error saying that 'int' object has no attribute 'split'. So added te enumerate referencing [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769921/attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-split)
But i sill get the same error.

```
enterreleased_date = []
released_country = []
released_year = []
for i in enumerate(df['released']):
    date = i.split("(")[0]
    country = i.split("(")[1].replace(')','')
    released_date.append(date)
    released_country.append(country)

df['released_country'] = released_country
df['released_date'] = released_date
df['released_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['released_date'])

df['released_year'] = df['released_date'].dt.year
df['released_month'] = df['released_date'].dt.month

#drop the unneccessary columns --yearcorrect was created by accident so we'll delete that as well
df.drop(['year','released','released_date','yearcorrect'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['logbudget'] = np.log(df['budget'])
df['loggross'] = np.log(df['gross'])
df.head(3) code here
```

Comment: `enumerate` returns tuples of two elements based on the index in the original iterable. i.e. `list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])) == [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]` Seems like you don't need it because you don't refer to the index.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling this:

```
for i in enumerate(df['released']):
```

`enumerate(x)` return a tuple object of 2 elements. 1st the number *i* of sample in  *x* and 2nd the *i-th* element in *x* itself. What do you get as `i` then is a tuple of the two elements per iteration. If you are using .split for a string, you need to write:

```
for i, string in enumerate(df['released']):
```

So now you get the two elements inside the tuple of each iteration. And then you can use `split()` as: `string.split()`.

Try:

```
for i in enumerate(df['released']):
    print(i)
```

And:

```
for i, string in enumerate(df['released']):
        print(i)
        print(string )
```

To see the difference.

EDITED: As @flakes suggests, it seems like you don't actually need to use enumerate. As for-loops in python are wiser than other languages and they iterate over elements in arrays/lists/etc and don't need a number to help them. `for elem in df['released']:` would be enough.

Comment: but when I code for elem in df['released']: it gets error...the same attributes error saying 'int' doesn't have the attribute split, not 'tuple'.

Comment: @ennswty I can't tell if I can't see your dataframe. I presumend values in df['released'] are strings, because .split is a string method. What are you trying to do? I do not understand trying to splint a integer by `")"`.

Comment: @ennswty Provide a few rows of your dataframe or your column as an example to see how it is.

Comment: for i in enumerate(df['released']):
    date = string.split("(")[0]
    country = string.split("(")[1].replace(')','')
    released_date.append(date)
    released_country.append(country)  
Is this what you meant? because this one worked.

Comment: -@RobertoT sorry ididn't know how to add code in the comment so i just posted an answer to this thread to answer your question

Comment: The issue with `.split()` is that it is a method for string class, that is why you get that error, it looks like you are using in integers. Paste here the first 5-10 examples of your column `'released'` to see what is inside the column. In your original post (editing it) or as a comment here, as you want.